# MySQL select 1 of multiple rows with same field based on where clause

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to select my entire table but where there are duplicate id's, only select 1 of them based on the data in a different field.

For example if my table looks like this

[image]

I want to select all rows, but if there are 2 of the same id, select only the row with `Billing` as the address type.

Comment: Is it ok to assume that `Billing` will be there only for ids which are duplicates?

Comment: Just an idea. Where clause should contain 2 conditions. First one checks that there is only one row with specific ID. It can be done by executing a subquery with count. The second condition checks if address type is billing. OR operation should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
select * from Table1 
where (AddressType='Billing') or
(AddressType='Shipping' and ID not in (select ID from Table1 where AddressType='Billing'))
order by ID
```

**Explanation:**

1st condition is to filter only `Billing` address types.

2nd condition is to filter `Shipping` address types which do not have `Billing` with the same ID.

Result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00483/9)

Comment: This should work assuming Billing and Shipping are the only address types and there's never more than 2 rows with the same Id

Comment: @jussius: Based on the data sample, this will work. Also, `ID` seems to be the only field used to specify the relation between those records.

Comment: This only returns rows with billing type. I need it to return shipping if there isnt a duplicate row with billing

Comment: @Sam: This will return all billing types and shipping if there is no billing type for that ID. Did you check the query in Fiddle link?

Comment: I think this has worked, I was just prioritizing the wrong one. Once I swapped it around to prioritize shipping over billing it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
SELECT *, ADDRESS
FROM (SELECT MIN(ID), ADDRESSTYPE
      FROM YOUR_TABLE
      GROUP BY ADDRESS) X
```